# Azure Blob to Azure SQL tables creation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, bulkinsert

I am trying to convert  BLOB Files into SQL DB Tables in Azure using BULK INSERT.

Here is the reference from the Microsoft: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/preview-loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-sql-database/

My DATA in CSV looks like this
100,"37415B4EAF943043E1111111A05370E","ONT","000","S","ABCDEF","AB","001","000002","001","04","20110902","11111111","20110830152048.1837780","",""

My BLOB Container is in Public Access Level.

Step 1: Created Storage Credential.  I had generated a shared Access key (SAS token).

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL Abablobv1BlobStorageCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2017-07-29&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacup&se=2018-04-10T18:05:55Z&st=2018-04-09T10:05:55Z&sip=141.6.1.0-141.6.1.255&spr=https&sig=XIFs1TWafAakQT3Ig%3D';
GO
```

Step 2:  Created EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE in reference to Storage Credential

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE Abablobv1BlobStorage
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, LOCATION = 'https://abcd.blob.core.windows.net/', CREDENTIAL = Abablobv1BlobStorageCredential );
GO
```

Step 3 BULK INSERT STATEMENT using the External Data Source and DB TABLE

```
BULK INSERT dbo.TWCS
FROM 'TWCSSampleData.csv'
WITH ( DATA_SOURCE = 'Abablobv1BlobStorage', FORMAT = 'CSV'); 
GO
```

I am facing this error:

> Bad or inaccessible location specified in external data source
>   "Abablobv1BlobStorage".

Does anyone have some idea about this?

I changed the Location of EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE to Location = abcd.blob.core.windows.net/invoapprover/SampleData.csv Now I get, Cannot bulk load because the file "SampleData.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.). For both statements using Bulk Insert or Open Row Set. I was not sure which access should be changed because the file is in Azure blob not on my machine, any ideas for this??

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following query

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK  'TWCSSampleData.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'Abablobv1BlobStorage',
   SINGLE_CLOB) AS DataFile;
```

Make sure the file is not located inside a container on the BLOB storage. In that case you need to specify the container in the Location parameter of the External Data Source. If you have a container named "files" then the location should be like 'https://abcd.blob.core.windows.net/files'.

More examples of bulk import [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/sql-bulk-load/load-from-azure-blob-storage/LoadFromAzureBlobStorage.sql).

Comment: I get same error as before, "Bad or inaccessible location specified in external data source "Abablobv1BlobStorage". "
I want to use direct bulk insert statement, instead of parsing.

Files are located inside the container so how could the syntax differ???

Comment: Hey I changed the Location of EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE to
Location = https://abcd.blob.core.windows.net/invoapprover/SampleData.csv

Now I get,
Cannot bulk load because the file "SampleData.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).
 For both statements using Bulk Insert or Open Row Set. I was not sure which access should be changed because the file is in Azure blob not on my machine, any ideas for this??

Comment: OK Thanks, I will Update the question

Comment: As I recommended, you did have to change the Location you have a folder/container named invoapprover created on that BLOB

Comment: Hey I changed the Location of EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE to Location = abcd.blob.core.windows.net/invoapprover/SampleData.csv Now I get, Cannot bulk load because the file "SampleData.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.).

Comment: This is a different error than the one you originally posted.

Comment: yes as I changed the Location directing to the file in BLOB. So now I get this error

Comment: Hey Alberto, OPENROWSET Statement Worked finally I can select the data but while inserting I am getting  error like,
"Failed to execute query. Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."
Here is my SQL Query,
INSERT INTO dbo.TWCS SELECT(
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
   BULK  'invoapp/SampleData.csv',
   DATA_SOURCE = 'Alobv1BlobStorage',
   SINGLE_CLOB) AS DataFile);

Comment: @guptak & Alberto: This would a great conversation to have in [chat](chat.stackoverflow.com). But not in comments here.

Comment: Anyhow I fixed it in different way. thanks for support!

Comment: hi Gupta, how did you fix your problem "Cannot bulk load because the file "SampleData.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)"? what access or permission did you change please?